# C# Speech - Creating a loop and ask the text-to-speech synthesiser to count

Tags: c#, winforms, text-to-speech

I am working on a speech recognition program in c#. I would like my speech recognition to count numbers. 
this is what I had tried so far,

```
if (e.Result.Text == "count numbers")
        {
            for (int count = 1; count <= 10; count++)
            {
                speechSynthesizer.Speak(); // what should I put here?
                tbOutput.Text += count; 

            }
```

Thank you

Comment: Speech recognition isn’t text to speech synthesis, please correct your question

Comment: take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: If you don't have a Grammar configuration file (`.sraxml` or `.srgxml` - there's a Grammar builder/validator, distributed with the Microsoft Speech SDK, which also includes a pre-built number/currency/dates grammar), you can simply build a `Dictionary<int, string>` and just `speechSynthesizer.Speak([Your Dictionary][count]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use count.ToString():

```
for (int count = 1; count <= 10; count++)
{
    speechSynthesizer.Speak(count.ToString());
    tbOutput.Text += count; 
}
```